# Violating RegExp: Every string that is smaller or equal "001700"

Tags: regex

i have a unique challenge.

i want to create a google analytics filter for a custom variable that only returns a value if the given string is smaller or equal than '001700'. yeah, i know that a string can't be smaller, still i need to find a way to make this work.

oh, and if you ask: no there is no way to convert that string to a number (according to my knowledge - via a google analytics filter - and that is what i have to work with in this case).

so basically, i have

```
000000
000001
000002
000003
...
...
999998
999999
```

and i need a regular expression that matches

```
001700
001699
001698
...
...
000001
000000
```

but does **not** match

```
001701
001702
...
...
999998
999999
```

sub question a) **is it possible?** (as i have learned, everything is possible with regExp if you are clever and/or masochistic enough)

sub question b) **how to do it?**

thx very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
^00(1700|1[0-6][0-9]{2}|0[0-9]{3})$
```

[See it](http://www.rubular.com/r/PVX7c3gumq)

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with RegEx:

```
/00(1([0-6][0-9]{2}|700)|0[0-9]{3})/
```

Explanation:

00 followed by

- 1 followed by 0 to 6 and any 2 numbers = 1000 - 1699

or

- 1700

or

- 0 followed by any 3 numbers = 0000 - 0999

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do

**[see this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/30/10-oddities-and-secrets-about-javascript/)**

Eg:

```
alert('your numericle string'.replace(/\d+/g, function(match) {
    return parseInt(match,10) <= 17000 ? '*' : match;
}));
```

> JavaScript calls our function, passing
>   the match into our match argument.
>   Then, we return either the asterisk
>   (if the number matched is under 17000) or
>   the match itself (i.e. no match should
>   take place).